# Failing installation of valgrind

Tags: gnome-terminal, downloads

I am trying to learn C with the guide, [Learning C The Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/), and in exercise 4 I have to download the program Valgrind, I do this with this command as shown in the book:

```
curl -O http://valgrind.org/downloads/valgrind-3.6.1.tar.bz2
```

But when I do this, the terminal goes nuts and print this:

```
m'þ¯àÑá¿T0K©ÄÂORBâ¡ 'úuÉÚ¢Ã$ ¼ æuµ1D5YQ�kN��<�cݖ�@P&j��)JU"D4��A�����5p�m�iDٲS��>�cQ�srQ1D��kW.
9��"��jX�
"!�f�w:�V�D��!���|�����$+�
B�T�0CK0��N$�9�ER��G�IN�wp���Q�
                                     ��϶�L,��z勩��P�@����^
                                                              ���1��öû_%Cß÷;íx:3àRPD.J!è"ñìgíÿ¾èýOµé )¨eMð  þUdTù¶bà'z)PÈEL)AILBP0éC×-+¤Ñ1LR
                      ß;UFÇïlmÙI8
cVN8áÄítaoQ¬Ð±Làä´
                      öÈvHDÁÄ´4¤)JÒ.çÈãìÀð;âR�fI��R&�"�^��r%S���pãÕvÖ-VÉXXfM8ãUIXXØdTQÈ4¥HÂÊ¢dLW+c$aP&"åAâ&L©¢"­fYaMAUDÄ6T¨faeÌk®bðà¸§KÿREð&
                                      e9ÞÉ?)¹ú¯bk åÓêÅ!üóI°P¤ 
R¥Q)¡)R* (Ä0ðT¹ªæðîü8Ý 
                               ìÜ&àð¿HB¦ÍÐñ.f0ü3üdPB'Í´#ÅPCì»nËV³ÅÝ&�x�{8��;�~Kz�&��gD�{�h�;
`#�6���M�
         $�B��z1�7Rb��3���6L��Crd
�A�A�0#ĸ�I8ޛ[��)��Ά+�΢Y���;7��g)�D�(��Oo�[�
���C��%!T�PMS!I@�SJ4�ҭ+ER�.�
                                   IãÑÜ'#JôE3¶'h:EÕî
                                                          p!��L
H\��3.01��Mo�ofF����
                     �MC:�A�l�MA�8%�[|���'s�E@��"U@
0P�P����h��)79�ư§¡ã=ÈF6ÅÑ²ïÈ#Ô�-���I0�T�A|Y�
                                   ·«7÷ßDuÅ£f

+¤Ä$wÄþ8½!ñ'Öä.l¤è                          Ü.å0Ä¶ÁªÁî"%Ck$JOqü
Z(½&UëøÏä×FS3   Çg
øIÜÒèZ-j¢$aÕ'Æ/÷?=
                          òÛà?­+ 5EEI9î÷Ü¯³ËüJFI1©DÌsçXÛ62É®pnÈËmR¡$LÈEäNbáaFP´¹Z3·&jÈ©jXæ9k2,ÀÀ%ä  pÄuäJ¡sl#BR/"0¨ø$îÀKyµ¬0h I ¿ 8À fþwú;ÿF­ëîÞ!
áh<vPU 4ë©¡QóeéZÜ¨¹.áíð+ôÆó Ý/ôÜÁØgÜù¬I_fä)rµF?³j öØ»ìëÏ_ç­&º´$Ä¾èaà äaÐ-÷YÓðÀAû
                                           ç¾vå 4rO Ýør½ä1%%-4!Bkæ0èÿoÿ¯ðÿùÿ?üû?ôøßÖÿÿ÷»ÿüßòÿ÷ÿÙÿªï¯ãÿÏþ?üÿþöþ:mÿÝÿ¿îÿÃÿÿüßöoçÿß÷7þý¿û¿ðýtÝÿÄÿÈÛ»¿ù>&ßþ?øÿòÿÇÙÿÝèTÁäaÝñ ÿßõ$Æõ ¤üÂHÛÿÔú¨2ÂÕe DË­¦¬PýPÿT
           ë7/ùÔpD#ücøjM(
ÏòC     D 
           e1þQçúöáÔOð·ÿúðTä<z¤,ò!Õ©¹mG����uBLK
                                                            IF0�       F���3z��إ�*�S��`�q�$8dQQK�R�:*��F�!��b�����LMFCFZ�!�&Jk
� A�B%��x\mQZ[���l�c��C�,f"C@�N!V������*[�L%(��"�84��\�������
��
hvem02@HP-computer:~$ ^C;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c
hvem02@HP-computer:~$ ^CÞxaæz   µÒ)mUP¬Ýì¨=òC²mæÂ¹U;ÎÇc®Ïæðaáõ×hvem02@HP-computer:~$ 
             µuAôÇ Öß!.Ækð#äèT< 4%çhØ;�Ef�,IrP�9d�M%��p�tD�,kv�w}O�
62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c
```

What is going on here, and how can I fix it?

Side note: I'm new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the terminal and run:

```
wget -c http://valgrind.org/downloads/valgrind-3.6.1.tar.bz2
```

or if you want you can download and also extract valgrind-3.6.1.tar.bz2 using curl with this command:

```
curl http://valgrind.org/downloads/valgrind-3.6.1.tar.bz2 | tar jx
```

Comment: Number 2 seams to work.